# How do I interpret and implement this formula?

Tags: expected-value, matlab, notation, t-distribution

I am trying to implement in MATLAB a formula for the posterior distribution of the degrees-of-freedom parameter $\nu$ from a paper by Villa & Walker linked [here](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/bitstream/handle/2152/43313/2014_Villa.pdf?sequence=1).  The formula goes as follows:

$\pi(\nu|\mu,\sigma^2,x)\propto\prod_{i=1}^{n}\{\frac{1}{B(1/2,\nu/2)}(\frac{1}{\nu\sigma^2})^{1/2}(1+\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{\nu\sigma^2})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}\}\times\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2(\nu+1)}B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\sigma^2\nu}B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})}\exp\{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}\mathbb{E}_{\nu}[\log(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\nu\sigma^2})]+\frac{\nu+2}{2}\mathbb{E}_{\nu}[\log(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2(\nu+1)})]\}$

for values of $\nu=1,...,\nu_{max}-2$

Here's what I know so far.  The $B$ refers to the Beta function and the first term is a product term.  The $\exp$ indicates that everything in brackets will be the exponent to which $e$ is raised.  In the paper, it says that $\mathbb{E}_{\nu}$ is the expected value with respect to $f_\nu$, which is a shifted, scaled $t$ distribution.

I'm lost on how to calculate the following portions:

$\mathbb{E}_{\nu}[\log(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\nu\sigma^2})]$ and $\mathbb{E}_{\nu}[\log(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2(\nu+1)})]$

Could someone break down how to do this, ideally for MATLAB?  Thanks!

Comment: When working with complicated formulas it's crucial to get them exactly correct.  In particular, $f_\nu$ is not a t distribution: it is a shifted, scaled version of a t distribution.  Readers unaware of this would face an difficult problem whose solution would be the incorrect one for you.  Instead, simple manipulations of the integral enable you to set $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ for the purpose of computing the expectations.  But the more basic question is why?? The paper states "The above expressions are not analytically tractable." What do you hope to achieve by computing them?

Comment: Hi @whuber, I'm hoping to replicate the results in the paper for my own edification.  I've been interested in exploring using the t-distribution for Bayesian analysis and having come across this paper, I'm trying to see if I can employ their methods used.  Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with how to implement what they are calling for.